# AngularJS Bootstrap UI datepicker issues

Tags: angularjs, uidatepicker

My datepicker is not working properly.

HTML

```
<div datepicker-config class="datepicker input-group">
    {{ dateOffer }}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{ format }}" name="dateOffer" ng-model="dateOffer" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" ng-readonly="true" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

If I am setting date by selecting it, I am getting proper value in input box

```
20.07.2015 (this is dd.mm.yyyy)
```

By looking at expression {{ dateOffer }} I am seeing

```
"2015-07-20T12:54:43.898Z"
```

which is okay too.

But when I am posting data and seeing it by `console.log($scope.dateOffer)`, the value is

```
Tue Jul 28 2015 14:54:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

which is odd. Have in mind that when loading page I am setting `$scope.dateOffer = new Date();`

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.dateOffer = new Date();
```

CONFIG

```
angular
    .module('offerCreateUpdate')
    .directive('datepickerConfig', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            controller: function($scope, datepickerPopupConfig) {
                datepickerPopupConfig.closeText = 'Some text';
                datepickerPopupConfig.clearText = 'Some text';
                datepickerPopupConfig.currentText = 'Some text';
                datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup = 'dd.MM.yyyy';

                $scope.today = function() {
                    $scope.dt = new Date();
                };
                $scope.today();

                $scope.clear = function() {
                    $scope.dt = null;
                };

                // Disable weekend selection
                $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
                    return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
                };

                var today = new Date();
                $scope.minDate = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 30);

                $scope.open = function($event) {
                    $event.preventDefault();
                    $event.stopPropagation();

                    $scope.opened = true;
                };

                $scope.dateOptions = {
                    startingDay: 1,
                    showWeeks: false
                };

                var tomorrow = new Date();
                tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                var afterTomorrow = new Date();
                afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
                $scope.events = [
                    {
                        date: tomorrow,
                        status: 'full'
                    }, 
                    {
                        date: afterTomorrow,
                        status: 'partially'
                    }
                ];

                $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
                    if (mode === 'day') {
                        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
                            var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                            if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                                return $scope.events[i].status;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return '';
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's simply how your browsers console is choosing to format it.  Everything above seems correct

Comment: Could you create a plunkr (or whatever you prefer) of this? you are getting the last (the 28th) because when you call `new Date();` you are getting the current date and time, today being the 28th. Maybe you are instantiating it at the wrong time? More code (maybe the controller where you are setting this up) and/or a plunkr would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine, your understanding is wrong

Input filed has some formatted result because Angular UI changes your date value to some proper format.

Expression will also have formatted value because it is handled by angular itself.

But when you do console.log(date), it will print date.toString(). So whatever you are getting in console.log is just a toString of your date object.

Comment: Please be careful as those three days are not the same. The first two are 20th, the third is 28th.

Comment: I didn't see that. My bad. Can you create plnkr for the same

Comment: If I am not setting any of date, the console.log($scope.dateOffer) gets undefined. It is strange because expression {{ dateOffer }} still returns right date. So my model must be set. I can not find a solution.

Comment: @be-codified show the code where you are setting all this stuff. I have a hunch you are just instantiating in a weird order.